# How to change the GAE to python3? Since i am developing a Django website.

Tags: django, google-app-engine

How to change the GAE to python3? Since i am developing a Django website. (How can Google still running python 2.7=_=

Comment: what makes you think python 2.7 is an obsolete version of python?

Comment: show us your resesrch so far. there is lots of info about this with trivial googling.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to move to Python 3, you need to run on the flexible environment:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/

Comment: Could u tell me how by step by step? I know that i am lazy.